# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not working with NSNotificationCenter

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, ipad, jsonmodel

I have a MasterDetail app that I am working on that will be used to show players (as in sports) and detail stats. The list of players is called from a Postgres Database and parsed from JSON using the JSONModel. So far, I am able to get all of the data that I need from the Postgres DB, and display it perfectly in the MasterView. I am using the NSNotificationCenter to pass the data from the Master to the Detail view (I fetch the data using a function in the MasterView). I am able to pass the data accurately to the Detail view, but for some reason, my didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not working right. I obviously did something wrong, but I have no idea what it is. Here are the important parts of the code:

**In the MasterViewController.m viewDidAppear:**

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

//fetch the feed from the Postgres Database

[JSONHTTPClient getJSONFromURLWithString:@"http://myurl" completion:^(NSDictionary *json, JSONModelError *err) {
    NSError* error = nil;
    _feed = [[PostgresFeed alloc]initWithDictionary:json error:&error];

    //Print the data fethced to NSLog in JSON format
    NSLog(@"Players: %@", _feed.players);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"myNotification" object:nil userInfo:json];

    //reload the table view after data collected
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    }];
}
```

**and I collect that info in my DetailViewController.m like so:**

```
- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSLog(@"%@", notification.userInfo);
    NSArray *playerData = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"player"];
    NSDictionary *firstElement = [playerData objectAtIndex:0];

    nameLabel.text = [firstElement objectForKey:@"name"];

}
```

**and then my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` in my MasterViewController**

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


Player *selectedPlayer = [_players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (_delegate) {
    [_delegate selectedPlayer:slectedPlayer];
    }
}
```

There you have it. If you want me to post more or if you want code from the DetailViewController.m, MasterViewController.h, or PlayerSelectionDelegate.h, just let me know.

As a note, I originally created this based off of the Ray Wenderlich iPad SplitView app tutorial a while back. And yes, I am new to this all.

Comment: is `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` getting called? Have you tried to set a breakpoint in there? At first glance either `_delegate` is nil or the tableview's delegate is nil.

Comment: You should do some logging to see where things are going wrong, but you really shouldn't be using an NSNotification to pass data to the detail view. If this is a split view based app, the master view controller should know what the detail controller is (through self.splitViewController.viewControllers[1]), so there's really no need to use a notification.

Comment: I set the breakpoint at the`Player *selectedPlayer =`... and it paused the app when I clicked on a name in the TableView. @rdelmar, what do you mean that I shouldn't use an NSNotification? Why? I am not saying your wrong (I honestly don't know), but it is working for me right now and unless I know of a good reason to stop using something that is working, then I will keep using it. If I am doing something wrong, please tell me what and why and I will gladly stop doing it.

Comment: It's not really wrong to use a notification, but notifications are usually used when you need to notify multiple objects, or when you don't know (or it's hard to get a reference to) what the receiving object will be. In your case you can easily get a reference to the detail view controller. You should also try a log after "if (_delegate)" to see if you're getting there. It's not clear what your problem is -- you say you can pass the data, and didSelectRowAtIndexPath is being called, so what's not working?

Comment: What is wrong? The delegate, detail VC and notification seem unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the NSNotification in

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
 //Here you have the NSDictionary from the json
[JSONHTTPClient getJSONFromURLWithString:@"http://myurl" completion:^(NSDictionary *json, JSONModelError *err) {
    NSError* error = nil;
_feed = [[PostgresFeed alloc]initWithDictionary:json error:&error];

//Print the data fethced to NSLog in JSON format
NSLog(@"Players: %@", _feed.players);
[JSONHTTPClient getJSONFromURLWithString:@"http://myurl" completion:^(NSDictionary *json, JSONModelError *err) {
NSError* error = nil;
_feed = [[PostgresFeed alloc]initWithDictionary:json error:&error];

//Print the data fethced to NSLog in JSON format
NSLog(@"Players: %@", _feed.players);
//Assuming that you have the players in the same order as your list
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"myNotification" object:nil userInfo:[[json objectForKey:@"players"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
 }];


Player *selectedPlayer = [_players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if (_delegate) {
[_delegate selectedPlayer:slectedPlayer];
}
}
```

And in your DetailViewController :

```
- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
NSLog(@"%@", notification.userInfo);

 nameLabel.text = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"name"];
```

}

Comment: All right, I think that we are back on track with this one and almost there. I placed the code above in the appropriate spaces, but I left out the first `[JSONHTTPClient getJSONFromURLWithString...` because it looks like a copy paste error, right? (I tried putting it in just in case it wasn't, but I get a ton of syntax errors). But, I see now that when ever I select a name, it re-fetches the Player data from the DB, but nothing is showing in the DetailView. Whenever I select a name, it displays (null) in the log for `NSLog(@"%@", notification.userinfo);` in my DetailViewController.m

Comment: that means the notification.userInfo is null from the didSelectRow method.

Comment: Sorry, I left some data out, when I run I get the print out from the NSLog in DVC.m, and only when I select a name do I get null back... In the `NSLog(Players...)` in the didSelectRow method, I get the data also. I feel like an idiot...

Comment: so have you found what you're leaving out?

Comment: Nope, that's why I feel like an idiot! I have no idea how I get all data fine in the DVC (proved by the NSLog), but get nothing for the `nameLabel.text = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"name"];`!!

Comment: OK, so the data is only getting to my DVC at the start of the run. When I select a name, the data does not make it over to the DVC, so something is wrong with the way I pass the data in didSelectRow method.

Comment: There are times, when people can be stupid, and then there is me. So there is actually nothing wrong with the methods that you have been showing me, and everything works WONDERFULLY!!!!!!. I had retardedly forgot that I had changed the name of my key, and in the `NSNotification` function I was using the OLD KEY!!! I fixed that and IT WORKS NOW!!!!!!!