# StoryBoard segue not working?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm trying to change the text on the DetailedViewController but every time I click on the cell I get this error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'MySegue''

This is how my code looks like.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [feedsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:indexPath];

    UILabel *title = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:0011]; 
    NSLog(@"TITLE; %@", title.text);

    DetailViewController *nextView=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];
    [UIView  beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextView animated:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This is my -prepareForSegue

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {

        // Get destination view
       DetailViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];


        // Pass the information to your destination view
        vc.title.text = @"lol";
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you instantiating `DetailViewController` if you are using segues??

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have a segue with that identifier in the storyboard? Check your storyboard.

Comment: Of course i clicked on it , the picture isn't loading , I'll try with a different browser, don't you i would know what to do...

Comment: Why are you using `indexPath` as a sender to the segue?

Comment: What should I use as a sender ?

Comment: I got this error

2013-07-06 19:48:20.396 Social App[68937:14003] -[UILabel copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0aab50
2013-07-06 19:48:20.411 Social App[68937:14003] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa0aab50'

Comment: Check the `DetailViewController` for that. And now I noticed , why are you performing a `segue` and immediately you push a `viewcontroller`?

Comment: Yes I got it working but I'm wondering how would I transfer the title.text into DetailedView ?

Comment: use `NSNotificationCenter` with a `NSDictionary` as parameter that has the `title.text` as object.

Comment: I responded in this post [send with NSNotificationCenter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479737/didselectrowatindexpath-not-working-with-nsnotificationcenter/17483720#17483720)

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17506591/label-not-changing-with-segue

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

#### Tapping a `UITableViewCell` would fail to perform the storyboard segue.

## tl;dr - Forgot to change default "reuse identifier" in `dequeCell..`

My segues were fine. The destination view controller happened to also be a tableView controller, and I had not changed the boilerplated "reuse identifier". Preparing for segue (loading the destinationVC) would fail, silently, and so no segue would be called; it only LOOKED like a segue failure.

Hope it helps someone, somewhere, beneath the great blue sky...