# label not changing with Segue

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, segue

I have a label on my DetailViewController and it's not changing when I try to edit it.

This is how my code currently looks like

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MySegue"]) {
        // Get destination view
       DetailViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSLog(@"Goes here");

       vc.titleLabel.text = @"My new UIlabel";

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show the code where you declare `titleLabel` in `DetailViewController` , also make sure you connect `titleLabel` to the label on storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `NSNotification` or better in your case use this via `NSUserDefaults`:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"My Label" forKey:@"detailTitle"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronise];
```

and in the viewWillAppear of the Detail you read it:

```
self.titleLabel.title = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"detailTitle"];
```